# How to ask the user from for a single word in Alexa Skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to develop an Alexa skill where Alexa asks the user for a single word (and than uses the word in sentence).
The user should be able to response with just the word, without any phrase around it. The word can be any word found in the dictionary.

So I am trying to create Intent with an Utterance like this:

```
{word}
```

The first question is: What to use for the `{word}` slot. There is `AMAZON.SearchQuery` which is for phrases, not for words, but maybe that is good enough.

Unfortunately, when I try to build the model I get:

```
Sample utterance "{word}" in intent "GetNextWordIntent" must include a carrier phrase. Sample intent utterances with phrase types cannot consist of only slots.
```

So I really need a phrase around the slot, which is not what I want.

How can I create an Intent (or do it some other way) to ask the user for a single word?

I found this project: https://github.com/rubyrocks/alexa-backwardsword which claims to be a skill, that asks the user for a word and says it backward. Unfortunately the project does not really explain how it deploys itself and how it works in detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use AMAZON.SearchQuery intent with a "variable only" as utterance.
You can use it with other slot type.

##### Why?

Because it will enter in conflict with **ALL** your intents.

```
{
    "name": "ResponseIntent",
    "samples": ["{response}"]
},
{
    "name": "QuestionIntent",
    "samples": ["play a new question"]
},
```

When a user wants to invoke other intents, it will work occasionally and route them to the ResponseIntent most of the time. Because the response is a searchQuery and it can be anything.

What if the user just want to quit your skill at the same time?

- User: `Alexa, stop`
- Alexa: `That's not the correct response`
- User: `Alexa, quit!`
- Alexa: `That's not the right response!`
- User is frustrated.

It will generate friction. That's why it requires other words.

Creating an Alexa skill requires thinking differently.
It is not a web application, or a voicemail and it can be quite challenging sometime.

There is no button to press to interact with your skill.
A skill is not a one path direction. Yet, the user can do whatever he wants at anytime: ask for help, invoke other intents, quit your skill, ...

What you can do is, based on the context, provide a specific slot type. For example, if you expect the word to be an animal, then you can use a variable only as utterance:

```
"{animal}",
"the {animal}"
```

If you use the AMAZON.Animal slot type.
There are [plenty of slot type](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/slot-type-reference.html#list-slot-types) available and you can also [extend one](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/create-and-edit-custom-slot-types.html#extend-slot) or [create your own slot type](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/create-and-edit-custom-slot-types.html#add-edit-type) with the values you expect. (or even create a [dynamic](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/use-dynamic-entities-for-customized-interactions.html) one)